Is it possible to "group" log messages for multil-line processing in fluent-bit?
I have a multi-service Docker project, with multiple containers all shipping their logs to journald. The log messages show up with the CONTAINER_NAME attribute filled out, along with a MESSAGE and bunch of other fields. I'm using fluent-bit to aggregate logs for later visualization in Grafana/Loki.
The project is in Python, and occasionally I'll get a multi-line traceback. I have multi-line support working well in fluent-bit, the only issue is that fluent-bit doesn't group the messages by CONTAINER_NAME when processing, so I'll end up with a traceback from service1 that doesn't end properly and eats lines from another service into its aggregated log message.
Example:
(service1)   2024-05-01 00:00:00 [info] initializing service
(service1)   2024-05-01 00:01:00 [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
                  File ..., line 123 in initialize()
                    (foo, bar) = setup()
                                 ^^^^^^^
                  TypeError: 'NoneType' is not iterable
(service2)   connecting to remote host abc
(service2)   connection established
(service1)   2024-05-01 00:02:00 [warn] attempting to reinitialize after failure...

In this example, service1 and service2 don't have the same log format, so my fluent-bit multi-line configuration thinks that the messages from service2 are part of the traceback.
Is there a way to group messages together and process the independently by the CONTAINER_NAME field?
fluent-bit.conf:
[SERVICE]
    Flush        1
    Daemon       Off
    Log_Level    info
    Parsers_File parsers.conf
    Plugins_File plugins.conf

[INPUT]
    Name            systemd
    Path            /var/log/journal
    Systemd_Filter  _SYSTEMD_UNIT=docker.service
    Tag             untagged

[FILTER]
    Name                  multiline
    Match                 untagged
    Multiline.key_content MESSAGE
    Multiline.parser      multiline-traceback-regex,python
    Buffer                true

[OUTPUT]
    Name stdout
    Match untagged

parsers.conf
[PARSER]
    Name        docker
    Format      json
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
    Time_Keep   On

[MULTILINE_PARSER]
    name          multiline-traceback-regex
    type          regex
    flush_timeout 1000
    rule      "start_state"   "/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+.*$/"    "cont"
    rule      "cont"          "/^(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d).*$/" "cont"

